# How to differentiate between each client connections in nanomsg socket library

Tags: linux, sockets, nanomsg

Am using nanomsg library with

int sock = nn_socket (AF_SP, NN_PAIR);

assert (nn_bind (sock, url) >= 0);

Now I want to know how to differentiate each connection in server if client connects.

In Regular Linux TCP Socket, we will get new socket fd on every connection accept,
am expecting some thing like that in nanomsg.

In below link am trying to use - Pair (Two Way Radio)

http://tim.dysinger.net/posts/2013-09-16-getting-started-with-nanomsg.html

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can by default.

Messages come in, and whenever a message comes in, you process it. There's no additional data on which client connected, or where the message came from.

Thus, my suggestion would be to let every client identify itself by a UUID at the start of every message, or wrap the messages in a JSON like format of which one key is used by the client to identify itself.